# Boot into new linux kernel 4.1.4 Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: kernel, 15.04, configuration, macbook, macbook-pro

I installed the a new linux kernel(4.1.4) in Ubuntu on my MacBookPro (Take not I am using rEFInd to dual boot ubuntu and OSX) but Ubuntu doesn't boot into the newer kernel. When selecting os to boot into it gives me the option to boot into Ubuntu with kernel 3.19.15 along with OSX.
 Also when I navigated to the /boot directory I noticed that no executable for the newer kernel didn't exist. Is there a way to get ubuntu to boot into the new kernel.

I used the following commands to install the new kernel (4.1.4)

```
$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.1.4-unstable/linux-headers-4.1.4-040104_4.1.4-040104.201508031330_all.deb

$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.1.4-unstable/linux-headers-4.1.4-040104-generic_4.1.4-040104.201508031330_i386.deb

$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.1.4-unstable/linux-image-4.1.4-040104-generic_4.1.4-040104.201508031330_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.1.4*.deb linux-image-4.1.4*.deb
```

Comment: You can currently boot ubuntu and it just doesn't use the latest kernel?

Comment: How did you install the kernel? is something wrong with the kernel the official repositories provide?

Comment: @xangua  When seleting an os to boot from using rEFInd it gives me Ubuntu with kernel 3.19.15.  I followed these instructions to install http://www.yourownlinux.com/2015/08/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-1-4-in-linux.html

Comment: @BMicraft No, unfortunately it doesn't use the latest one. I added additional information to the post  to clarify the nature of the problem

Comment: @TheEnigma Try `update-grub`. This could work, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: @BMicraft Yeah I tried that it didn't work.

Comment: Please be more specific: Did you encounter the same problem or were you unable to boot it?

Comment: @BMicraft Still had the same problem afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo update-grub
```

Updates grub, as the command suggests.

Comment: This did not work, it still booted into the same kernel